# Assert that given arguments are passed to a method regardless of call order

Tags: phpunit

In testing method A, method B is called multiple times. I want to assert that at least one of those calls uses specific arguments, but I don't care when that call is made.

How can I construct a PHPUnit test to assert this?

I've searched Google and StackOverflow for the solution with no luck, and the docs aren't proving to be much help, either.

I've tried using this helper function:

```
protected function expectAtLeastOnce( $Mock, $method, $args = array() ) {
    $ExpectantMock = $Mock->expects( $this->atLeastOnce() )->method( $method );

    $this->addWithArgsExpectation( $args, $ExpectantMock );
}
```

This, however, doesn't work because it expects *every* call to use the specified arguments, even though it would accept any number of calls above none.

Similar questions:

- [Test that method is called with same parameters, among others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607190/test-that-method-is-called-with-some-parameters-among-others) - recommends using `->at()` which requires knowledge of invocation order, so not a solution
- [PHPUnit stubs - make expected calls independent of the order of invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038038/phpunit-stubs-make-expected-calls-independent-of-the-order-of-invocation) - unanswered; comments recommend using a testing framework, which I'm not interested in doing

EDIT: Here's my implementation of the accepted answer:

```
protected function assertMethodCallsMethodWithArgsAtAnyTime(
    $InquisitiveMock,
    $inquisitiveMethod,
    $InitiatingObject,
    $initiatingMethod,
    $expectedArgs = array()
) {
    $success = false;

    $argsChecker = function () use ( &$success, $expectedArgs ) {
        $actualArgs = func_get_args();
        if (
            count( $expectedArgs ) === count( $actualArgs )
            && $expectedArgs === $actualArgs
        ) {
            $success = true;
        }
    };

    $InquisitiveMock->expects( $this->any() )
        ->method( $inquisitiveMethod )
        ->will( $this->returnCallback( $argsChecker ) );

    $InitiatingObject->$initiatingMethod();
    $this->assertTrue( $success );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not very elegant, but you can check the method arguments manually by using a callback and set a flag when the right arguments were found:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('Class', array('theMethod'));

$call_done = false;

$params_checker = function() use (&$call_done) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    if (1 == count($args) && "A" == $args[0]) {
        $call_done = true;
    }
};

$mock->expects($this->any())
    ->method('theMethod')
    ->will($this->returnCallback($params_checker));

$mock->theMethod("A");

$this->assertTrue($call_done);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm going to see if I can't get this working. Are you missing a parenthesis on the first line?

Comment: Pardon my obtusity, but where is `$sut` coming from?

Comment: my fault, $sut was supposed to be $mock. Edited again

Comment: Took me a bit to adapt it to my own needs, but this works perfectly! Thanks so much.